# Primality radii and Sidon sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics, goldbach-type-problems, sidon-sets

I learned tonight what a Sidon set is, in a book about Erdős. This notion inspires me the following question :

For $n$ a large enough composite integer, say $r>0$ is a primality radius of $n$ if both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are prime. Let $g(n)$ be the number of primality radii of $n$, and $(r_{0}(n),\cdots, r_{g(n)-1}(n))$ the sequence of primality radii of $n$ in increasing order. Now let $\phi$ such that $(r_{\phi(k)})_{k=1..l(n)}$ is a subsequence thereof that is a Sidon sequence (which implies $l(n)\leq g(n)$). For all $\varepsilon>0$, is there a composite integer $n(\varepsilon)$ and a Sidon subsequence of its sequence of primality radii of size $l(n(\varepsilon))>(1-\varepsilon)g(n(\varepsilon))$?

Edit : after some more thinking, I think the answer is no, as $g(n)$ is expected to be $\asymp n/log^{2}n$ while the maximal size of a Sidon set  in $[1,n]$ is expected to be $\sim n^{1/2}$.
So here comes the natural modification of the above question:

For all $\varepsilon>0$, is there a composite integer $n(\varepsilon)$ and a Sidon subsequence of its sequence of primality radii of size $l(n(\varepsilon))>(1-\varepsilon)\sqrt{g(n(\varepsilon))}$?

Comment: [For general subsets of integers, $|l|>c\sqrt{|g|}$ for any $c<2/25$](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/5697697194B5B02F7316E2ABBFDA6A24/S0008439500003118a.pdf/sidon_sets.pdf).